# Where does yum store the temporary packages

Tags: yum

When we do a `yum install` or `yum update` where does yum stores the downloaded packages in the system.

Answer (score 0):

By default `yum` stores its cache in `/var/cache/yum`

Answer (score 0):

According to system, architecture and repository yum stores temporary packages in following:

```
/var/cache/yum/<arch>/<prod>/<repo>/packages/
```

where contents in `< >` are variables.

Comment: @karthik : If you find my answer helpful and resolved your issue, Please mark the answer accepted. So that, it will come at top of other answers and will helpful to others who refer this question.